# How mongodb handles reads from secondary nodes?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-replica-set

My default connection string sets read preference to primary and it has all the replica set urls.

I can see my reads going to secondary when I use this code

```
let db = MongoPool.db()    
let collection = await db.collection("tableName", {readPreference:'secondaryPreferred'});
let result = collection.findOne( {userName: "" });
```

But, how is this connection handled with a connection pool?

Is a new connection created to the secondary node for this read?

Basically, how mongo handles reads directed towards secondary, does it make a new connection, or all reads go to the primary node and the primary node re-directs those reads to secondary?

Answer (score 1):

The driver directs queries to the appropriate node.

In a replica set topology, the driver is connected to all nodes and sends queries to the secondaries directly.

In a sharded cluster, the driver is connected to mongos routers which forward the queries to appropriate replica set nodes of the individual shards.

Comment: if the connection pool size is 10, then are there 30 connections given that we have three nodes, one primary and two secondaries?